# On Click of select box ,Option to be entered/displayed in to the next text box using Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
   <select id="studentinst" size="6">
  <option value="1">First Installment</option>
  <option value="2">Second Installment</option>
  <option value="3">Third Installment</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth Installment</option>
  <option value="5">Fifth Installment</option>
  <option value="6">Sixth Installment</option>
  </select>

  <input name="instalmentnamefdtls" type="text" size="20" value=""/>
```

My Question is that if i click on First Installment nor any Installment , it should be displayed in the the input text box .How to achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your best friend! So easy to Google this question!

```
$(function() {
    $('#studentinst').change(function() {
        $('input[name="instalmentnamefdtls"]').val($('#studentinst option:selected').text());
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLape/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#studentinst').change(function()) {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        $('#instalmentnamefdtls').val('First Installment');
    }
});
```

Add id to your textbox:

```
<input name="instalmentnamefdtls" id="instalmentnamefdtls" type="text" size="20" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery change() event. Like this

```
$('#studentinst').change(function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $(':input#instalmentnamefdtls').val(txt);
});
```

also replace your input with this

```
 <input id="instalmentnamefdtls" name="instalmentnamefdtls" type="text" size="20" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#studentinst").change(function(){
    var select_val =$('#studentinst option:selected').text();
    $("input[name='instalmentnamefdtls']").val(select_val);
});
```